# Simple PowerShell scripts

Tags: powershell, scripting

I need some help with creating a PowerShell script that does the following:
Connect to a network share with an authenticated user account
Then check for files in a source folder.
If the files exist, make a copy of all the files to a destinated folder,
If the files don't exist stop the script.

Any help would be appreciated I'm still very new to PowerShell.
Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you know what needs to be done, good starting point! What do you need help with? Where are you stuck? Where's the code you've already written? :)

Comment: Did you know Get/Push/Pop-Location https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/push-location?view=powershell-7.2 - that might help to start

Comment: Ive gotten the checking the file and copying all contents down. I'm struggling with the connecting to a network share with an authenticated user